# Error not catch on Try Catch on Route level

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using async await in my functions. My Controller level is able the catch the error, but when returning to route level. Error is not catch, and only return data:{}. What am i doing wrong here?

```
//route
router.get('/user', auth, async function(req,res){
try{
const userId = req.body.userId
const user = await UserController.getUser(userId)
res.status(200).send({data:user})
}catch(err){
res.status(400).send({message:err})
}
}
```

```
//Controller
exports.getUser = async function(userId ){
try{
const user = await User.findOne({_id:userId })
return user
}catch(err){
return err
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe the code is not throwing an error., instead is emitting an event. Just a guess

Comment: the error shows on the Controller Level when i Tried to set a break point. But when returning the err to Route. Doesn't Jump to Catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already catching the error in the controller level, you won't be able to catch it anymore in the route catch block unless you throw it again after catching it in the controller catch block i.e:

```
exports.getUser = async function (userId) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
    return user
  } catch (err) {
    // throw the error again
    throw(err);
  }
}
```

However, this approach is wasteful, if you intend to handle the error in the route call back function, then there is no need catching it in the controller. The right thing to do would be to just write the controller function without any try/catch block:

```
exports.getUser = async function (userId) {
    return await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
}
```

Then handle the error in the route call back like you are already doing.